# Hiding horizontal scroll bars in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll

I have a div that has horizontal scrolling enabled (overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;).
The thing is, I want to keep the horizontal scrolling but I don't want to show the scroll bar. in iOS it works great but Android devices show the bar :-\

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#scroller").bind('touchstart', function (ev) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) $(this).scrollTop(1);
  var scrollTop = document.getElementById('scroller').scrollTop;
  var scrollHeight = document.getElementById('scroller').scrollHeight;
  var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('scroller').offsetHeight;
  var contentHeight = scrollHeight - offsetHeight;
  if (contentHeight == scrollTop) $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop-1);

});
```